# Trigger to apply user mapping to logins on database creation

Tags: sql-server, trigger, permissions

Does anyone have any example triggers that apply user mapping on database creation?

Comment: If you could elaborate on what you mean *exactly* by "user mapping", I could make a more meaningful example. What is your current process to do this manually, again, *exactly*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no evidence of the OP having done any research to even start to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very quick example that will create a user `blat` given an existing login `blat` in all new databases created (this won't work for attach/restore). You could extend this to adding them to roles, granting permissions, even building the list based off of some query from `sys.server_principals` in `master`, `sys.database_principals` in another database, or your own users table. Note that it doesn't have any error handling.

```
CREATE TRIGGER DBCreate_MapUsers
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_DATABASE
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @db NVARCHAR(510);
  SET @db = CONVERT(SYSNAME, EVENTDATA().query('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName[1]/text())'));
  SET @db = QUOTENAME(@db) + N'.sys.sp_executesql ';
  EXEC @db N'CREATE USER blat FROM LOGIN blat;';
END
```